# How to compare list with actual string in Python?

Tags: python, list, hostname

I am trying to get the `hostname` of my machine in Python. I am able to get the hostname using `socket`. Now I need to compare this `hostname` with `colo` list and see whether that `hostname` belongs to which `datacenter`. Either it is from dc1 or dc2 or dc3.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

colo = ['dc1', 'dc2', 'dc3']

hostname = socket.gethostname()
```

How to check whether that hostname is from which colo and then print it out that colo?

Sample Hostname will be like this -

```
dc1dbx1145.dc1.host.com
dc1dbx1146.dc1.host.com
dc1dbx1147.dc1.host.com
dc1dbx1148.dc1.host.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split on `.` and test the second value:

```
location = hostname.split('.')[1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> hostname = 'dc1dbx1145.dc1.host.com'
>>> hostname.split('.')[1]
'dc1'
```

You probably want to verify that the name you found is indeed a recognized location with:

```
if location not in colo:
   print 'Not a recognized location'
```

If you don't know what part might be the location, use:

```
location = next((part for part in hostname.split('.') if part in colo), None)
if location is None:
    print 'Not a recognized location'
```

Comment: Dang it, beat me by 4 seconds!

Comment: Call me Lucky Luke! :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for suggestion. But it might be possible that hostname can get changed, meaning fields in the hostname can get re-ordered for whatever reason. I don't know what that reason will be. It is not going to happen for sure but just giving an example.  So still I should try to do it like this? or there will be some better way to do that?

Comment: @SSH: It might be better to use `hostname.split('.')[-2]`, because presumably the sub-domain cruft is the part that can get changed trivially, but the `host.com` part is likely to be stable. If things could change even more unpredictably, your best bet is to iterate through all the parts of hostname and find the first one that's in `colo`. But that's a bit hacky.

Comment: @SSH: And of course Martin edited in the same idea as a readable one-liner before I could finish writing the second half of my comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your hostname is consistent and always with this format, you can try something like:

```
data = hostname.split('.')
if len(data) == 4 and data[1] in colo:
     print "Datacenter: %s" % data[1]
else:
     print "Unknown hostname"
```

The `if` statement is here just to avoid exception if you encountered error with the hostname fetching.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the following snippet:

```
colo = ['dc1', 'dc2', 'dc3']
hostname = socket.gethostname()
term= hostname.split('.')[1]
print filter(lambda x: term in x,colo)
```